# How do I make an API call to GitHub for a user's pinned repositories?

Tags: http, curl, github, github-api

On GitHub, a user can have [pinned repositories](https://github.com/blog/2191-pin-repositories-to-your-github-profile).

There's also the [Repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) section of the API describing how to make requests that involve repos. You can also get information about the orgs a user is part of as described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225679/how-to-get-all-user-repositories-by-github-api-including-pinned-repositories) (which can be pinned).

However, I want to access a user's pinned repos. For example given the following profile:

[image]

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
$ curl -s <some endpoint with some parameters> | <some pipeline with some filtering>
str
liffy_diffy
spiralify
micro-twitter
kit
xdoc
```

So I'm wondering:

- What is the endpoint and parameters do I need to get a user's pinned repos?

I was able to use the [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) gem to parse the html. However, it seems like I should be api to accomplish the same thing with a simple HTTP request:

```
$ ./get_user_pinned_repos mbigras
str
liffy_diffy
spiralify
micro-twitter
kit
xdoc
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# get a user's pinned repos
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

if ARGV.length != 1
  STDERR.puts "usage: get_user_pinned_repos <username>"
  exit 1
end

username = ARGV.first
profile_url = "https://github.com/#{username}"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(profile_url))
page.css("span.repo").each { |repo| puts repo.text }
```

Answer (score 12):

**An update to the original answer:**

The [changelog](https://developer.github.com/v4/changelog/2019-03-30-schema-changes/) for GitHub GraphQL schema (2019-03-30) mentions that the
pinnedRepositories will be deprecated or removed by 2019-07-01. GraphQL API users are requested to use `ProfileOwner.pinnedItems` instead.

Examples to retrieve pinned repositories using `ProfileOwner.pinnedItems`:

**Example 1:**

```graphql
query {
    user(login:"kranthilakum") {
        pinnedItems(first: 5, types: [REPOSITORY, GIST]) {
            totalCount
            edges {
                node {
                    ... on Repository {
                    name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Try Example 1 in the GraphQL API Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20user(login%3A%22kranthilakum%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pinnedItems(first%3A%205%2C%20types%3A%20%5BREPOSITORY%2C%20GIST%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

**Example 2:**

```graphql
query {
  repositoryOwner(login: "kranthilakum") {
    ... on ProfileOwner {
      pinnedItemsRemaining
      itemShowcase {
        items(first: 5) {
          totalCount
          edges {
            node {
              ... on Repository {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
        hasPinnedItems
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try Example 2 in GraphQL API Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repositoryOwner(login%3A%20%22kranthilakum%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...%20on%20ProfileOwner%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pinnedItemsRemaining%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20itemShowcase%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20items(first%3A%205)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasPinnedItems%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 9):

### Outdated

You can get pinned repository using [Github GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) :

```graphql
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "bertrandmartel") {
    ... on User {
      pinnedRepositories(first:6) {
        edges {
          node {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repositoryOwner(login%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...%20on%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pinnedRepositories(first%3A%206)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

You can request it with [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) with :

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: bearer TOKEN" --data-binary @- https://api.github.com/graphql <<EOF
{
 "query": "query { repositoryOwner(login: \"bertrandmartel\") { ... on User { pinnedRepositories(first:6) { edges { node { name } } } } } }"
}
EOF
```

You can parse the JSON output with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser :

```bash
username=bertrandmartel
curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer TOKEN" \
     -d '{ "query": "query { repositoryOwner(login: \"'"$username"'\") { ... on User { pinnedRepositories(first:6) { edges { node { name } } } } } }" }' \
     https://api.github.com/graphql | \
     jq -r '.data.repositoryOwner.pinnedRepositories.edges[].node.name'
```

Comment: message":"Field 'pinnedRepositories' doesn't exist on type 'User'

Answer (score 2):

Go to this URL and type your username and hit the "go" button. There you will see your pinned repos as a JSON responce.

[Click here](https://gh-pinned-repos-5l2i19um3.vercel.app/)

Or else, you can replace your username in the below link.

```
https://gh-pinned-repos-5l2i19um3.vercel.app/?username={Username}
```

For more info: Click [here](https://nsadisha.medium.com/get-pinned-github-repositories-as-json-a9d6243c9da4) or [here](https://dev.to/nsadisha/get-pinned-github-repositories-as-json-1hff)