# Github Pinned Repositories REST call without using graphQl

Tags: rest, github-api, graphql

I'm trying to sort out how to make a call to Github's API to get a hold of my pinned repos but I can't seem to find anything from Github's documentation using a REST call.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352056/how-do-i-make-an-api-call-to-github-for-a-users-pinned-repositories) which uses graphql and does what I want but I'm not looking to spin up another server for this project.

so far I'm using `https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/repos`. Has a good amount of what I want but nothing for pinned repos.

anyone know?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it's possible GitHub built this feature entirely with the GraphQL API and no REST endpoints exist. Note that [v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) of the GitHub API is entirely in GraphQL and not REST. Any reason you don't want to use GraphQL? You shouldn't need another server. GraphQL API calls are normal HTTP requests.

Comment: I'm not opposed to Graphql at all. in fact, I was initially using it. The problem is, everything I looked up on how exactly to use Graphql mentioned servers.

Comment: Ok cool! You only need a server if you're looking to run your own GraphQL API. Just consuming the GitHub GraphQL API won't require any severs :) Check out the v4 link above for details on how to get started

Answer (score 0):

As @Wilhelm said, you do not need your own servers to make a GraphQL call.
Have a look [here](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/) to get started.

Briefly,

- `https://api.github.com/graphql` `POST` request
- `Authorization: bearer <token>` header
- `{ "query": "query MyQueryToGithub { ... }" }` JSON payload

Comment: One issue with this is that there's no anonymous access to GraphQL. So if, for example, you wanted to dynamically include a list of your pinned repos via JS in a public web page, this is problematic and you'd either expose your creds publicly, or need a server to make the call.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an easier way to get pinned github repos.
No keys or auth required.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kentaylorappdev/get-pinned-repos

Check it out.