# How to retrieve the list of all Pinned github repositories of a person?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to get all the `Pinned` repositories from GitHub of a person, but I'm getting all the repositories at once... how to I filter it?

I'm using the the `Github` api which is returning the following code:

```
{
  "current_user_url": "https://api.github.com/user",
  "current_user_authorizations_html_url": "https://github.com/settings/connections/applications{/client_id}",
  "authorizations_url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations",
  "code_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "commit_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "emails_url": "https://api.github.com/user/emails",
  "emojis_url": "https://api.github.com/emojis",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/events",
  "feeds_url": "https://api.github.com/feeds",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/user/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}",
  "hub_url": "https://api.github.com/hub",
  "issue_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/issues",
  "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/user/keys",
  "label_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/labels?q={query}&repository_id={repository_id}{&page,per_page}",
  "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/notifications",
  "organization_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}",
  "organization_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "organization_teams_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/teams",
  "public_gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/public",
  "rate_limit_url": "https://api.github.com/rate_limit",
  "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}",
  "repository_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "current_user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/user/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "starred_gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/starred",
  "user_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}",
  "user_organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/user/orgs",
  "user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "user_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}"
}
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What GitHub API URL call did you make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [GraphQL API call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43358500/6309) to get pinned repositories, but no GitHub API.

A [similar GitHub community thread](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Retrieve-pinned-GitHub-projects-using-the-REST-API/td-p/2515) was requesting such an API, but for now, it does not exist to get what the web GUI offers:

[image: pinned repos -- https://dyjpb62732.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/196i69B449A8B4331950/image-size/large/is-moderation-mode/true?v=1.0&px=999]

Comment: Yep I want to get this pinned repositories =)
So they do not have an API to get this pinned repositories?

Comment: @user2535338 Exactly. As far as I can see, they do not have a GitHub API for getting pinned repositories.